# how to compare value in swift optional

Tags: swift, option-type

```
var someString: String? = "a"    
someString = "b" 
// or someString = nil
```

**Condition:** someString is not nil and "a"

**Example:**

```
if someString != nil && someString != "a" {

}
```

Is it possible to condition a single?

Comment: Well, since you've now completely changed your question... I have no clue what you're actually asking.  The code you have will work, although it doesn't match the text.  (!= s/b == according to the text)

Comment: someString = "b" or someString = nil

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you're asking.  "Is it possible to condition a single?" doesn't make sense.  None of your examples match the "Condition" you give in your question.  The simplest expression that actually meets the "Condition" listed in your question is given in my answer below.

Comment: I'm sorry. 
My question seems silly.

Comment: Not so much silly as unclear.  If you're wanting to check that `someString` is not nil and IS NOT "a" then it's something like Antonios answer `someString != nil && someString! != "a"`  If you want something is not nil and IS "a" then it's simpler since you can collapse it to my answer.

Comment: I do not speak English well. 
So it seemed a silly question. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you mean that you would like to test for `someString != nil` *and* `someString != "a"` in a single logical expression (and not two in and).

No, I don't think that's possible using the built in operators, but doable implementing a String extension like this:

```
extension String {
    func isDifferentThan(value: String?) -> Bool {
        return value != nil && self != value?
    }
}
```

and you can use as follows:

```
someString = nil
"a".isDifferentThan(someString) // Return false

someString = "b"
"a".isDifferentThan(someString) // Return true

someString = "a"
"a".isDifferentThan(someString) // Return false
```

**Addendum**: A more elegant solution is to define your own logical operator. I have used `!~=` but feel free to use your own.

```
infix operator !~= { associativity left }
func !~= (a: String?, b: String?) -> Bool {
    if a == nil || b == nil {
        return false
    }

    return a != b
}
```

Tested as follows:

```
someString = nil
someString !~= "a" // Returns false

someString = "b"
someString !~= "a" // Returns true

someString = "a"
someString !~= "a" // Returns false

someString = nil
someString !~= nil // Returns false
```

You can fine tune it when dealing with `nil` values (such as add a check for both having `nil` and returning `true`, in case you want the condition "both sides are nil" to evaluate to true)

Comment: Thank you. 
The answer I wanted.

Comment: Added another solution - better in my opinion

Answer (score 7):

The correct way in **Swift 3** is to use a multi-clause condition:

```
if let bString = someString, bString != "a" {
    print("bString: '\(bString)' is not nil and is different from 'a'")
}
```

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md

Comment: That really possible now? Finally!

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with a where clause:

```
if let forcedString = someString where forcedString != "a" {
    print("Yea")
} else {
    print("Err")
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

swift 1.2 for `var a:int?; var b:int?` has matrix

```
nil == nil; // true
nil > nil;  // false
nil > 2;    // false
2 > nil;    // true
2 > 1;      // true
```

Comment: Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands

Answer (score 1):

One trick:

```
func existsAnd<T: Equatable>(x:T?, _ it:T ) -> Bool {
    return x.flatMap { $0 == it } ?? false
}

var str : String? = "hello"
existsAnd(str, "hello")
str = nil
existsAnd(str, "hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collapse the whole thing using the optional unwrapping operator:

```
if someString? == "a" {
```

Comment: But it is these two conditions. 
Is it possible to condition a single?

Comment: This is what I would have guessed, but doesn't compile (at least anymore!) 
 `error: '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript`

Comment: this will not compile

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party but how about just this (assuming you do want to compare strings):

```
if someName.compare(displayName) == .OrderedSame{
  //true
}
```

Comment: by the way you must unwrap optionals before use this is the point right? If you don't have a value there is nothing to compare.

Answer (score 0):

This extension of Optional will compare Optionals and its wrapped value.

```swift
extension Optional: Comparable where Wrapped: Comparable {

    // Optional <=> Optional

    public static func < (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v < rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func <= (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v <= rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func >= (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v >= rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func > (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v > rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }


    // Optional <=> Wrapped

    public static func < (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Wrapped) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v < rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func <= (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Wrapped) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v <= rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func >= (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Wrapped) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v >= rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func > (lhs: Optional<Wrapped>, rhs: Wrapped) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .some(let v): return v > rhs
        case .none: return false
        }
    }


    // Wrapped <=> Optional

    public static func < (lhs: Wrapped, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch rhs {
        case .some(let v): return lhs < v
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func <= (lhs: Wrapped, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch rhs {
        case .some(let v): return lhs <= v
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func >= (lhs: Wrapped, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch rhs {
        case .some(let v): return lhs >= v
        case .none: return false
        }
    }

    public static func > (lhs: Wrapped, rhs: Optional<Wrapped>) -> Bool {
        switch rhs {
        case .some(let v): return lhs > v
        case .none: return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too much! Just use the `<`.